# Adding new Row [at RunTime] in DataGridView replaces the previous added Row

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, dapper

I want (When Button Clicked) previous row still exist in datagridview while adding new row (such that user can add as many rows as he/she want at runtime in datagridview).

I found many questions on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) regarding rows of datagridview but i cannot figure out them according to my problem. Second, i am new in Dapper and all answers using ADO.NET.

I have an idea that there should be an easy way of such problem.

I bind my datagridview to Orders Class.

Here is my Orders class...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    public class Orders
    {
        public int    ItemId      { get; set; }
        public string ItemName    { get; set; }
        public string Brand       { get; set; }
        public string Category    { get; set; }
        public int    Quantity    { get; set; }
        public int    Price       { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Select Button Click Event is..

```
private void btn_select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                db.Open();
            string query = "SELECT *FROM tbl_ItemDetail WHERE ItemName=@ItemName";
            ordersBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<Orders>(query, new { ItemName = txt_sell_item.Text });

        }
    }
```

When I enter ItemName as 'bread' then GUI is..

[image: When enter ItemName as 'bread']

But when I enter ItemName as 'bjn' then first row replaces with newest row..

[image: When enter ItemName as 'bjn']

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind your problem lies within your `button click event handler`, You are binding `DataSource` every time the user clicks the button which gives you one record as expected. Instead of assigning `DataSource`, write a insert statement which inserts record within your grid. By doing this, your issue will be surely resolved.

I'm not giving solution with code because I don't have my pc right now.

Comment: It is my application requirement that i should use DataSource.

Comment: The use of your `DataSource` is invalid within your click.